# Play ts files from browsers in android using hls.js

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have some TS files with index.m3u8 that can be played fairly in VLC and browsers like chrome and firefox in windows 7 (using hls.js). 

From a android 4.4.2 device, I tried to run the html file,,

firefox - it is working fine

**chrome 36.0 - it is working fine

chrome 60 - it is not working**

One more thing, 

`alert(window.MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"'));`

**returns false** only in chrome 60(android 4.4.2). 
I am fully confused about what is going on, can we play ts files from android browsers or there is any dependency?

Comment: The specified `codecs` should be supported. However 4.4.2 is known to have issues with HLS on certain devices.

Comment: @aergistal,  is there any alternative way apart from hls.js so that I can play ts from browsers efficiently?

Comment: also is it about the android version or with chrome? because in same android version, firefox is playing well.

Comment: no idea really. Did you try with `video/mp2t`?

Comment: wait, this is the mime type for .ts. This is what I added in IIS server mime type and that is working fine in my computer. But to run it on android browser I dont know what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are/were confused because native browser functions like...

```
 MediaSource.isTypeSupported()
```

...and others, refer to **NATIVE** support of media types and not something that has been added via a 3rd party library (like hls.js) post-engine compilation.

Native support of media types can only be added/registered during the Chromium engine compilation in a special way by developers.

However, if you're not a Chromium developer capable of adding additional native media types then your only alternative is to add non-NATIVE *"pseudo-support"* with tricks like...

```
 chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(e){});
```

...so as to catch certain urls (ie: .m3u8 streams) and redirect them to whatever optional service/functionality you may have added, like hls.js.

Most people's usage of hls.js is even lower-level by directly supporting HLS on a single media player on a page, which is a far cry from native support.

So in a nutshell what's confusing you is not understanding the difference between NATIVE browser support vs PSEUDO 3rd party support.